# secure_getenv() on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, clang, darwin

Why does `secure_getenv()` only works on my GNU/Linux system but not on macOS?
Compiling it there results in the following error:

```
main.cpp:31:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'secure_getenv'
    char* env_custom_path = secure_getenv("MY_ENV_VAR");
```

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)

> The **GNU-specific** `secure_getenv()` function

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

It's not a standard function, so it's simply not available on macOS.